# Are zero-knowledge proofs quantum-resistant?

Tags: zero-knowledge-proofs, post-quantum-cryptography

Are zero-knowledge proofs quantum-resistant?

Comment: Which proof system are you talking about?

Comment: It depends. For instance, SNARKs are not and STARKs are.

Comment: SNARKs and STARKs are not, by default, zero-knowledge proof systems @YoussefElHousni

Comment: @iwriteonbananas why STARKs are not quantum resistant ?

Comment: They are, but the question was about _zero-knowlege_ proof systems. STARKs are, by default, not zero-knowledge. @YoussefElHousni

Comment: Can you please develop your point a little bit more? According to the paper https://eprint.iacr.org/2018/046, starks are zero-knowledge. @iwriteonbananas

Comment: @YoussefElHousni "STARK" is a succinct non-interactive argument system which can be made zero-knowledge with a slight modification. The resulting argument system is called "zkSTARK".

Comment: Ok I was talking about ZK-STARKs. Precision matters. @iwriteonbananas

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is no generic answer to this question. Zero-knowledge proof (ZKP) systems can be post-quantum secure, but they need not be. It all depends on the cryptography on which the security of the ZKP rests.

There exist ZKPs that only use collision-resistant hash functions and hence are plausibly post-quantum secure. The most well-known examples are those using the [FRI protocol](https://vitalik.ca/general/2017/11/22/starks_part_2.html): [Aurora](https://eprint.iacr.org/2018/828), [Fractal](https://eprint.iacr.org/2019/1076), and [zk-Starks](https://eprint.iacr.org/2018/046) [*].

Other notable ZKPs like [Bulletproofs](https://eprint.iacr.org/2017/1066) or [Groth16](https://eprint.iacr.org/2016/260) rely on cryptographic assumptions (e.g. hardness of discrete log in elliptic curve groups) for which it is known they would be vulnerable to quantum attacks, if such attacks became practical.

[*] "zk-STARK" refers both to a security definition and to a particular family of FRI-based proof systems that satisfies it. The security definition does not mention post-quantum security, so it is the latter that is meant here.

Comment: I think Hyrax is based on DL, so not quantum secure.